# Script using "write" was working before and is now not working in Applescript

Tags: arrays, macos, file, applescript

I'm working on a homework reminder app. I recently asked a question concerning using "write" properly and had my question answered. My script was working perfectly, but now it has stopped writing anything to my file. I must have changed something, but I can't figure out what's wrong. Any suggestions?
(Please Note: This is still a work-in-progress and not everything is competed; however the part using "write" should not be effected)

Code:

```
set saveFile to (path to desktop as text) & "Script Log.txt"
set assignments to read file the saveFile from 1 to eof using delimiter "*"

repeat
display dialog "What would you like to do?" buttons {"New Assignment", "Delete/Edit Assignment", "Exit"}
set function to button returned of result
if function = "New Assignment" then

    display dialog "What subject is this assignment for?" default answer ""
    set subject to text returned of result

    display dialog "What do you need to bring home for this assignment?" default answer ""
    set materials to text returned of result

    display dialog "What is the assignment?" default answer ""
    set instructions to text returned of result

    (choose from list {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Long-Term"} with prompt "When is this assignment due?")
    set dueDate to result as text
    if dueDate = "Long-Term" then
        display dialog "When is this due?" default answer ""
        set dueDat to text returned of result
    end if
    set assignments to {assignments & (subject & ": You need to bring " & materials & " home. It is due on " & dueDate & ". For this assignment, you need to " & instructions & ".")}

else if function = "Delete/Edit Assignment" then

    (choose from list {item 1 of assignments} with prompt "Which assignmnet would you like to delete/edit?")

else if function = "Exit" then

    set fullText to ""

    repeat with i from 1 to number of items in assignments
        set thisItem to item i of assignments & "*"

        set fullText to fullText & thisItem
        if i is not number of items in assignments then set fullText to fullText & return

    end repeat

    my scriptLog(fullText)

    exit repeat
end if
end repeat

on scriptLog(thisText)
  try
    open for access file the saveFile with write permission
    write (thisText & return) to file the saveFile starting at eof
    close access file the saveFile
on error
    try
        close access file the saveFile
    end try
end try
end scriptLog

display dialog assignments
```

Comment: where,how does it stop? what if any errors do you get

Comment: There are no errors, and the code continues normally. It only does not log any text into "Script Log.txt".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The saveFile is not defined inside the scriptLog handler.

Change the top line : `set saveFile to (path to desktop as text) & "Script Log.txt"`

to a **property**, since it value is static. A property is automaticly global to the rest of the code and it's handlers.

`property saveFile : (path to desktop as text) & "Script Log.txt"`

The other thing to remember is that  **try** blocks can hide any errors when you are debugging so you should remember to comment them out if you are debugging.

Comment: Thank you! Now I remember what I changed– I moved the saveFile to the top because I will need it in other parts of the app later.

Comment: @Hippopoodlmus , have a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_fundamentals.html .  And in particular the section on Variables and Properties.  As you must use  Properties with consideration of value persistence..